# Why we need to return reference to istream/ostream while overloading >> and << operators?

Tags: c++, reference, stream, operator-overloading

What happens if I do not return `din` or `dout`, actually I'm reading a book in which writer returns back stream references

```
istream & operator>>(istream &din,vector &a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    din>>a.v[i];
    return din;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream &dout,vector &a)
{
    dout<<"("<<a.v[0];
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
    dout<<", "<<a.v[i];
    dout<<")";
    return dout;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason is a combination of several facts.

1. You want to be able to chain input and output operations as in

   ```
   in  >> x >> y;

   out << z << std::precision(10) << t << std::endl;
   ```

   so you must return something that allows `operator<<` again.
2. Since you want your operator to work on any `istream`, i.e. any object derived from `std::istream`, you cannot define

   ```
   operator<<(istream_type, object);    // take istream by value
   ```

   since this would only work for the specific istream type `istream_type`, but not for a generic `istream`. For that one must use polymorphism, i.e. either take a reference or a pointer (which will be a reference or pointer to a class derived from `std::istream`).
3. Since you only have a reference to the istream, you cannot return the istream object itself (which may be of a type not even defined at the point of the definition of `operator<<`) but only the reference you've got.

   One could get around this restriction by defining `operator<<` a `template` and take and return the `istream_type` by value, but that requires the `istream` type to have a copy constructor, which it may well not have for good reasons.
4. In order to envoke polymorphism one could, in principle, use pointers (to streams) rather than references. However, `operator<<(stream*,const char*)` is 
   not allowed in C++ (at least one operand must be of class or enumeration type).

   Thus, with stream pointers one must use function-call syntax and you're back with C-style `fprintf(stream*, args...)`.

   Moreover, pointers can be null or dangling, which in fact is their default state (when declared without initializer), while a reference can be assumed to be valid (it cannot be declared without initializer).

Comment: I'm not sure your last argument about pointers gets to the point. If these operators returned pointers, we would have to call them like `*(*(out << foo) << bar) << baz;` – surely no-one would want that sort of syntactic clutter.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant **No**. You didn't get my point. I edited the answer. One could (have) use(d) pointers instead of references *everywhere*, including the standard library and it would work as with references, expect for the issue of null and/or dangling pointers.

Comment: The "default state" of pointers is not "NULL or dangling", and it is easy to create a dangling reference without using pointers.  The reason for using references with stream functions is to allow chaining, and also because using references allows the operator to assume the object exists (i.e. the caller is responsible for providing a valid reference, and the operator does not need to check for validity, like it would with a pointer)

Comment: @Rob, I think your last point is what I meant with null or dangling pointer. A pointer declared without intitialiser is null or dangling. A reference cannot be declared without initialiser.

Comment: @Walter if you use a pointer in the parameter, you can't call these operators on rvalue streams. I've seen pre-C++11 code doing `std::stringstream(the_string) >> the_int`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yes, one cannot use stream pointers with `operator<<`. But one could use stream pointers with (overloaded) `output(stream*, args..)`, which is the C way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

In this case when the reference is returned you can combain the operator in a chain. For example

```
std::cout << "Hello " << "Rajat Verma";
```

This is equivalent to the following calls of the operator

```
operator <<( operator <<( std::cout, "Hello" ), "Rajat Verma" );
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              returns reference to std::cout
```

Answer (score 3):

One more thing is that ostream and istream standard objects such as cout and cin use a private copy constructors so they should be returned by reference not by value

Answer (score -1):

When you type:
 cout << vector; 
cout has the type of ostream so when you use " << " it does need to return an arguement with ostream type for cout to work