# Why do we need to return reference to the object when we're using operator overloads so that we can chain operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference, iostream

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, coords coord)
```

So i have this code right here, and can someone explain why by returning reference to the object, the operator can be chained and we can write codes such as `cout << coord1 << coord2;` (the coord1 and coord2 belongs to the coords class in case you don't know) ? And also what does returning reference to the object mean in this case, does it return a reference to the cout object or what so that we cannot create a copy of it? How does this work exactly behind the compiler?

I've tried removing the reference sign.

```
ostream operator<<(ostream &output, coords coord)
```

And it doesn't allow me to chain operators, so how does this work exactly?

Comment: you shuold read the error message you get when you return `ostream` rather than `ostream&`. Thats already big part of the answer. The other part is that you want to write to the same stream when chaining not to a different one (even if it was possible)

Comment: See dupe [Why we need to return reference to istream/ostream while overloading >> and << operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913009/why-we-need-to-return-reference-to-istream-ostream-while-overloading-and-o)

Comment: You seem to be saying all the right things, but as questions instead of statements. Yes, a reference is returned because you can't copy stream objects. Yes, it returns a reference to `cout` (in the case of `cout << coord1 << coord2;`). Yes. you return a reference so calls to the operator can be chained. You seem to understand everything correctly. As for how the compiler makes this work, that's something only the compiler knows. Not something you have to worry about in general.